# Trying to fix conversion warning

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I am getting the following error:

```
warning: conversion to ‘short unsigned int’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

for the method

```
template<typename T> bool get_int(FILE* IN, T* val) {
    T rc = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) << 3; i += 8) {
        int temp = getc(IN);
        if (temp == EOF)
            return false;
        rc |= (T)temp << i;
    }
    *val = rc;
    return true;
}
```

when I have the lines

```
unsigned short foo;
get_int<unsigned short>(IN, &foo);
```

How can I get rid of this GCC warning?

Comment: Forget the warning, your call is, on success, dereferencing a null pointer!

Comment: It's late :) Fixed the typo in my sample code. Thanks.

Comment: What line causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rc |= (T)(temp << i);
```

`(T)temp` is promoted to int again for the bitwise shift.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There's already a function to read multiple bytes of binary data: [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fread):

```
template<typename T>
bool get_int(FILE* f, T* val) {
    return fread(val, sizeof(T), 1, f) == sizeof(T);
}
```

Note that you don't have to explicitly specify the types when calling function templates - you can let deduction to its thing:

```
unsigned short foo;
get_int(IN, &foo);
```

Comment: Thanks. But, your solution will not work on big-endian machine.